# Convert.ToDouble doing something weird

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a user input string to a double by

```
Calculation.Rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

When I input 1, Rate is 1 as expected but when I enter 0.5, Rate becomes 5. What can be the reason for this?

Note:

I declared Rate as below:

```
private double rate;
//property Rate
public double Rate
{
    get { return rate; }
    set { rate = value; }
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse a double with how it is presented to your eyes, for example in the debugger.

Comment: Make sure your culture settings are correct. Maybe you live in a country that uses a comma instead of a dot...

Comment: try with 0,5 as input. As Styxxy mentioned, looks like culture issue.

Comment: yea that worked. Strange thing is when I enter 0,5(with comma) in the command prompt it is evaluated right but when I enter 0,5 (with comma) in the visual studio editor it does not accept. I mean Visual studio accepts (dot) but command prompt only accepts (comma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set yours culture for example to english:

```
var englishCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-EN");
var value = Console.ReadLine();
double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, englishCulture,  out Calculation.Rate)
```

The problem that you have is possible due to, you have a german culture or other(?) which expect ',' instead of '.' while reading/parsing float/double numbers.

Comment: should I do this 1 time or I should I add this code to every program?

Comment: It will works only in project which You do this because it's overrides system  cultureinfo.

Answer (score 1):

To check number decimal separator and group number separator you can do the following:

```
 var numberDecimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
 var numberGroupSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
```

I guess in your case '.' is used as a number group separator.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a problem with your culture settings.

Almost every Parse-function in .NET has an overload to provide him with culture settings. Culture settings contain information such as `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` which can be different from culture to culture. Use a current culture to convert your text to the double.

Example:

```
using System.Globalization;
...
CultureInfo myCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Calculation.Rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), myCulture);
```

Of course, this way you have to use this culture every single time you do a conversion. It would be better to make your culture the default culture on the active threat:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
...
// Set the current culture once on the active thread.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
...
// Now convert everything using this culture.
Calculation.Rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Be warning: This only works on the active thread. If you use multiple threads, set the culture on each threat.

In an ASP.NET application you can define the default culture for each request (or each threat that handles each request):

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-US" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you want to change the current culture for ALL your application, you might consider changing your culture settings in your Windows Control Panel in Windows under the Region-settings.